# Why is my first test in Postman/Newman hanging in Travis-CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postman, travis-ci, newman

**Tl;dr** I'm using Docker to run my Postman/Newman tests and my API tests hang when ran in Travis-CI but not when ran locally. Why am I encountering tests that run infinitely?

Howdy guys! I've recently started to learn Docker, Travis-CI and Newman for a full stack application. I started with developing the API and I'm taking a TDD approach. As such, I'm testing my API first. I setup my `.travis.yml` file to download a specific version of Docker-Compose and then use Docker-Compose to run my tests in a container I name api-test. The container has an image, `dannydainton/htmlextra`, which is built from the official `postman/newman:alpine` image like so:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "14.3.0"

env:
  global:
    - DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.26.2
    - PGHOST: db
    - PGDATABASE: battle_academia
    - secure: "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"
    - secure: "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"
    - PGPORT: 5432

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - npm rebuild
  - sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: api tests
      script:
        - docker --version
        - docker-compose --version
        - >
          docker-compose run api-test
          newman run battle-academia_placement-exam_api-test.postman-collection.json
          -e battle-academia_placement-exam_docker.postman-environment.json
          -r htmlextra,cli
```

And, my `docker-compose.yml` file has **4** containers:

1. client is the React front end,
2. api is the NodeJs/Express back end,
3. db is the database that the API pulls data from in the test environment,
4. api-test is the container with Newman/Postman and some reporters which I believe is built from NodeJs.

I hardcode in the environment variables when running locally, but the file is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  client:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    build: ./server
    environment:
      - PGHOST=${PGHOST}
      - PGDATABASE=${PGDATABASE}
      - PGUSER=${PGUSER}
      - PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD}
      - PGPORT=${PGPORT}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${PGDATABASE}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${PGUSER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./server/db/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  api-test:
    image: dannydainton/htmlextra
    entrypoint: [""]
    command: newman run -v
    volumes:
      - ./server/api/postman-collections:/etc/newman
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Now that the setup is out of the way, my issue is that this config works locally when I cut out `.travis.yml` and run the commands myself, however, putting Travis-CI in the mix stirs up an issue where my first test just... runs.[image]

I appreciate any advice or insight towards this issue that anyone provides. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue did not come from where I had expected. After debugging, I thought that the issue originally came from permission errors since I discovered that the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory got ignored during container startup. After looking at the [Postgres Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/12/alpine/Dockerfile), I learned that the files are given permission for a user called `postgres`. The actual issue stemmed from me foolishly adding the database initialization scripts to my `.gitignore`.

***Edit***
Also the Newman tests were hanging because they were trying to access database tables that did not exist.